# Edwards / Montgomery ECC with Weierstrass Implementation?

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, ed25519

So let's assume I want to perform Ed448 or Ed25519 digital signatures or want to perform a DH key-exchange. Assume further that those curves (Curve448 or Curve25519) are *required*.

But the problem is, that I have only a constrained device given, which only allows for Weierstrass-Computations. Alternatively I have a software library that can perform Weierstrass-Operations but not Montgomery / Edwards operations. "Operations" here denote point addition and scalar multiplication. Note further that both devices / libraries support arbitrary (Weierstrass) curves.

So this provokes the question:
**Is it possible to perform Edwards / Montgomery operations using a Weierstrass engine and if so, how?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are essentially asking if points in Edwards and Montgomery curves can be represented in Weierstrass coordinates. This is true; in fact, *any* elliptic curve over a field of characteristic $\neq2,3$ can be represented in Weierstrass form $\mathcal{E}_{w}^{a, b} : y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, and by extension its points can too.

The question, then, becomes “how easy is the conversion”?

For Montgomery curves of the form $\mathcal{E}_m^{A, B}: By^2 = x^3 + Ax^2 + x$, it is surprisingly [straightforward](http://saluc.engr.uconn.edu/refs/sidechannel/okeya00elliptic.pdf). You can map the point $(x, y) \in \mathcal{E}_m^A$ to the Weierstrass curve $\mathcal{E}_w^{1/B^2-A^2/3B^2,A(2A^2 - 9)/27B^3}$ via the map $((x + A/3)/B, y/B)$. The inverse map is obvious, $(Bx - A/3, By)$. If $B=1$, which is the case for every Montgomery curve used in practice, this simplifies substantially.

For twisted Edwards curves $\mathcal{E}_{e}^{a, d} : ax^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2$ (where Edwards curves are the subset where $a = 1$) [there also is a simple map](https://eprint.iacr.org/2008/013) to a Weierstrass curve, which consists of converting the curve to Montgomery format first. In particular, we can map $\mathcal{E}_e^{a, d}$ to $\mathcal{E}_m^{2(a + d)/(a - d), 4/(a - d)}$ via $(x, y) \mapsto \left(\frac{1 + y}{1 - y}, \frac{1 + y}{x - xy}\right)$, with inverse $(x, y) \mapsto \left(\frac{x}{y}, \frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)$. Composing theses maps with the above, we get maps to the appropriate Weierstrass curve $\mathcal{E}_w^{a, b}$. None of these conversions are terribly expensive compared to the cost of a scalar multiplication.