# Can specific Weierstrass curves be some benefit from Montgomery/Edward form?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I have noticed that DBL/diffadd in Edward/Montgomery form almost double fast than Weierstrass form[(EFD)](https://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/index.html), and curve25519 is empressive high-performance.The transformation between these forms can be covered by two **ModInv**s at most(even two **ModMult**s). So the scalar multiplication in specific elliptic curves like p256 or Secp256k1 could transfer to scalar_mult in Edward/Montgomery form.

1. Could these tranformation&AdditionChain&diffAdd be faster than the ordinary MADD&w-NAF&preCom methods?
2. Of course Curve25519 is designed for Montgomery form, but the wide spread Weierstrass curves also have well-designed prime number. To what extent will the curve parameters affected the performance of Montgomery/Edward scalar_mult?

Comment: I don't believe that the curves p256 or Secp256k1 can be converted to Edward/Montgomery form; curves in those forms always have a point of order 2, and p256/Secp256k1 don't have such a point

Comment: I have refered to the answer from [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27842/edwards-montgomery-ecc-with-weierstrass-implementation). I should have misunderstood thoes fomulars.

Comment: I've just learned that Weierstrass curve converted to Montgomery curve only stand with special conditions, e.g. 4|order(E), etc. I guess the traditionnal Weierstrass curves always designed to have prime order, perhaps on account of the security level&efficiency. But if the Montgomery curve state to have 128bits security level converted to Weierstrass form with order divisible by 4 also have the same security level. What's the meaning of such principle?

Comment: @scv10086 There are several caveats with non-prime order curves. Point validation is much more inefficient, small group attacks becomes possible, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curves P-256 and Secp256k1 cannot be converted to Montgomery or Edwards forms because they are of prime order.

Let's take the example of Secp256k1 and try to convert it to a Montgomery curve:

A Montgomery curve $by^2=x^3+ax^2+x$ has a point of order 2. Such a point verifies $2P=\mathcal{O}$ or think of it equivalently $P=-P$ which means $(x,y)=(x,-y)$ so these points are on the $x$-axis. It is obvious then that the point $(0,0)$ on a Montgomery curve has order 2. Now given the secp256k1 curve $y^2\equiv x^3+7 \pmod p$ where $p=2^{256}-2^{32}-2^9-2^8-2^7-2^6-2^4-1$, we are looking for points on the $x$-axis which means those that satisfy $x^3 \equiv -7 \pmod p$. There is [no solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%20x%5E3%3D-7%20mod%20115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663) to this modular cubic equation.

In general curve P-256 and Secp256k1 cannot be converted to Montgomery form because they have a prime order ($\ne 2$) and thus they cannot have a point of order $2$ (otherwise $2$ would divide a prime number beacause of [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))).

The same reasoning works for Edwards curve $x^2+y^2=1+dx^2y^2$ because the point $(0,-1)$ has order $2$ and the points $(\pm 1, 0)$ have order $4$.

Comment: this is not what wikipedia says in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve#Equivalence_with_Weierstrass_curves

Comment: @David天宇Wong wikipedia says you can find an equivalence of curves in general. The question here is about « specific » curves like p256 and secp256k1. These specific weierstrass curves have a prime order and the equivalence relationship doesn’t work because all montgomery and edwards curves have necessarily a composite order.

Comment: how right, it's only true for Montgomery -> Weierstrass. I missed "[Weierstrass] can be converted to Montgomery form if and only if $E$ has order divisible by four and satisfies the following conditions [...]"