# How to impelement mapping point Curve25519 to weierstrass point?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I am implementing a ECDH using Curve25519 to communicate two system. One system have library that use for weierstrass curve only, it can define with domain parameter like p, a, b, G_x, G_y. I have read and find that Curve25519 can converse to weierstrass, I can find that converse domain paramerter for Curve25519 here (https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-lwig-curve-representations-02.html). After that, I need converse point from Curve25519 to weierstrass, I find the mapping is (u,v) -> (x, y) = (u + A/3, v) but I do not understand that. Example with base point of Curve25519, (u, v) = (0x9, 0x20ae19a1b8a086b4e01edd2c7748d14c923d4d7e6d7c61b229e9c5a27eced3d9), after converse in weierstrass, base point is (0x2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad245a, 0x20ae19a1b8a086b4e01edd2c7748d14c923d4d7e6d7c61b229e9c5a27eced3d9), with A = 486662, B = 1. That seem not correct with mapping, so is that operator devision is not normal division. What exactly I need to converse point in form Curve25519 to weierstrass curve, thank you.

Comment: [related Q&A](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/27842/23623)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what is your question, I'm assuming you are not understanding why the mapping gives that particular result...

In ECC, all computations are carried out in a finite field. For Curve25519, all computations are done modulo $p = 2^{255}-19$.

To compute $u + A/3$, the division by three is actually $A$ multiplied by the inverse of $3$ modulo $p$. This inverse is the value that, when multiplied by 3, given 1 modulo $p$. This inverse is `0x5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555549`; you can check that if you multiply this by $3$ and compute the remainder of the division by $p$ it will give $1$. Carring out the rest of the computation (always reducing modulo $p$) will give the expected result `0x2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad245a`.

The modular inverse can be computed using the extended Euclidean algorithm or using Euler's theorem (which is computing the exponentiation by $p-2$).

Answer (score 0):

> I am implementing a ECDH using Curve25519 to communicate two system. One system have library that use for weierstrass curve only, ...

Curve25519 is the underlaying curve designed for X25519 Diffie-Hellman function ([details see RFC 7748](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7748)), it's designed to be more easily to implement correctly than Weierstrass curves.

Curve25519 and secp256r1 (or any other SECG curves) are **NOT** designed to interoperate with each other, if you don't have support for one of them, use the other; or if both are missing what the other have, use finite-field Diffie-Hellman key exchange.

Comment: Yes, they are not designed to interact with each other however as I mentioned the weiertrass curve implement can use with all domain parameter and I find Curve25519 parameter when perform in weierstrass curve. So in theory, I can use the weierstrass parameter to perform Curve25519 operation right? I try to reuse that implement, is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but no established software can do that at the moment. Most well-written libraries and programs are designed to work on pre-determined curves such as secp256r1, secp384r1, and secp521r1, they can't work on random curves you throw at them. Also, you can post a message to the author on Facebook ask about the motivation for drafting the document, the name is at the end of the draft you linked in the question, I doubt it achieves something non-trivially meaningful.

Comment: Yeah, I try something to test that. Thank for your answer.

Comment: There are some general-purpose libraries and hardware accelerators which can carry out ECC computations given the Weierstrass curve parameters, so it makes sense in those cases.

Comment: OpenSSL (except RedHat-nobbled builds) and Java (both the 'standard' Sun/Oracle/Open provider and the BouncyCastle provider) support arbitrary Weierstrass curves. 'Well-written' may be de gustibus, but those are indisputably established.